# Gradle Spring Boot project not working in Tomcat as a WAR

Tags: gradle, tomcat7, spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-7

I have a simple sample application written in Spring Boot using Gradle dependency. It says helloworld on calling localhost:8080/greetings. I packaged it as WAR and deployed it to a Tomcat as a myWebApp.war.

When i call localhost:8080/myWebApp/greetings i get 404. What am i supposed to infer from the below catalina.log

```
  Sep 17, 2014 1:43:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.54
Sep 17, 2014 1:43:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive D:\C813507\Tomcat7\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\webapps\cftsample.war
Sep 17, 2014 1:43:09 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(D:\C813507\Tomcat7\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\webapps\cftsample\WEB-INF\lib\tomcat-embed-core-7.0.54.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Sep 17, 2014 1:43:09 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(D:\C813507\Tomcat7\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\webapps\cftsample\WEB-INF\lib\tomcat-embed-el-7.0.54.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Sep 17, 2014 1:43:13 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [138] milliseconds.
Sep 17, 2014 1:43:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive D:\C813507\Tomcat7\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\webapps\cftsample.war has finished in 4,385 ms
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To run a Spring Boot application in a standalone servlet container you need to tell the container how to launch the application. You do so by extending `SpringBootServletInitializer` and overriding the `configure` method to provide the configuration classes for your application. This is described in the [getting started guide on converting a jar to a war](https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/).

You typically end up with a class like this:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    // Used when launching as an executable jar or war
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    // Used when deploying to a standalone servlet container
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so much clearer and more concise than Spring Boot's own documentation!

Comment: excellent. I found many people having the same issue while working with Spring boot first time.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the server used java 1.8 and compile with java 11, not working, when compile with java 1.8, it works!!