# Cannot access spring boot application after deployment in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, gradle, spring-boot

I have created a REST API using Spring boot. I am using gradle as my build tool. I have tested the application using the embedded container and it is working fine. I am able to access my application at `localhost:8080/foo/bar`.

Now I have deployed it to tomcat without any error.

```
Mar 17, 2016 1:58:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.65/webapps/foo.war
Mar 17, 2016 1:58:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 17, 2016 1:58:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.65/webapps/foo.war has finished in 623 ms
```

But I am now unable to access the application at `localhost:8080/foo/bar`. I can see that tomcat is running at `localhost:8080`

Here is the `build.gradle` file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.3.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

war {
    baseName = 'foo'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

configurations{
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
   compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
     compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
     compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.2.5.RELEASE'
     compile 'org.json:json:20151123'

     providedRuntime 'javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1'
     providedRuntime 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
     providedRuntime 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'

     testCompile("junit:junit")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.11'
}
```

I have an `application.properties` file with the following code

```
server.context-path=/foo
```

and my request mapping in controller is set to

```
    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping("/bar")
    public String bar(){
       // Code
    }
```

I tried what is mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884010/gradle-spring-boot-project-not-working-in-tomcat-as-a-war), but that is also not working.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class FooApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FooApplication.class, args);
    }

    // Used when deploying to a standalone servlet container
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(FooApplication.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use embedded tomcat and create executable jar?

Comment: @SMA I want this application to run on a server. I am not sure if making the application an executable jar will help in that case

Comment: @ak31 It will and imho it will be easier to maintain as the executable jar is ready to be installed as a service.

Comment: Check [this](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications#what-about-the-java-ee-application-server) for deploying in an application server

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle is that the preferred way of deploying applications? I've always deployed a war file to a tomcat server till now as I wasn't familiar that it could be done like this

Comment: @ak31 It is a matter of preference. I have several services on my server and I like to be able to start/stop them with `sudo service myProject.jar status/start/stop` like any other services. On the other hand, deployment via a war file is better integrated with continuous integration tools.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam your link has worked. I didn't have `extends SpringBootServletInitializer` in the application class.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle having seperate services for applications was something I wasn't aware of. I will definitely explore it further. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To deploy a Spring Boot application you have to have a configuration class which extends `org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer` and overrides `org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application)`

So when the application is deployed in a JEE Servlet container Spring Boot application will be deployed and served properly.

**Example**

```
@Configuration
public class AppServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

The `Application.class` is same class as in `SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);` in the main method

REF: [What about the Java EE Application Server?](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications#what-about-the-java-ee-application-server)